# 2016 Subaru Forester electrical problems

Tags: electrical, subaru, forester

I want to get an advice on what would be the right approach to deal with our leased car, Subaru Forrester 2016.

Our lease contract is for three years. We have another year until the end of the lease.

The car became problematic to start about a year ago. We spend about an hour trying to start it on some occasions. We took it to the dealership three times. We received all kind of feedback from them:

1. They could not find a problem.
2. They replaced the battery a few times.
3. They found another problem with some kind of led/sensor under the brake pedal (if I understood it right)
4. And yes, they also tried to blame us that we left some lights on. I made sure we did not.

Eventually, the car stalled in the middle of the freeway with my pregnant wife, my seven-year-old, and me inside it. Since then, I afraid to take my family in that car.

The car got towed away to the dealership on that day. They spent two days looking for the problem and replaced that led which I mention above.

I contacted Subaru USA and asked them to replace this car for the rest of the time of the lease. They are not going to do that. They only offered me $500 credit in the Subaru shop as a courtesy pay.

We left for a vacation of 20 days, and after we came back the car did not start again. The battery died. I had to call road assistance to jump start it. The technician told the battery should not die in 20 days. And remember, we just went to the dealership before vacation. And they tested it all. The Subaru just reiterated their offer for $500.

The car has also a problem with the sensor of the front seat belt. It starts beeping signaling to fasten the seat belt when the seat is completely empty. And there is no way to stop it. It is annoying. It is known to be a common problem. They adjusted the sensor a few times, but this problem always comes back after some time.

I know it often hard to find a reason for an electrical problem in the car, but it is very annoying. We are leasing because we want to avoid hassle dealing with a car. We liked driving this car before these problems started. I know Subaru cars are usually reliable. On one hand, maybe we just got unlucky. On the other hand, I do not want to lease another Subaru car next year and discover similar problems. We preferred to lease Subaru Forester in 2016 for its safety properties.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure we can answer this for you. it seems you are asking us for advice or opinion on what you should do with the vehicle. If the car is still under warranty (3yr/36k mile bumper to bumper), which I assume it is, then take it back to Subaru and have them fix it. It makes no difference if it's on lease or if you are buying it outright, the warranty should still cover your issues.

Comment: The problem is that we already took it 5 times to the dealership and electrical problems continue.

Comment: You can always take it to another dealership. If you try to do the work yourself, you can void your warranty. I get it's a PITB (believe me I get it). You cannot take it back to Subaru and expect them to take it off your hands (unless you trade it in and take it in the shorts on the lease), but you can expect them to fix the issues as long as it's within warranty. To me, you've taken the wrong tact with Subaru (corporate). You need to be pressing them to get it fixed, not to take it back.